# PowerCLI vSphere set-annotation

Tags: vsphere, powercli

I am able to set notes in annotation with below PowerCLI vSphere.

**Input: serverdetails.txt**

name,notes

Server 1, This is an application server : .Net

**Command:**

Import-Csv "C:\temp\serverdetails.txt" | %{ Set-Vm -Name $*.Name -Description $*.Name -Confirm:$false }

**Current Output in annotation i get is as below, complete content in one line.**

This is an application server : .Net

**However, i need below output in annotation (in two lines):**

Line 1: This is an application server

Line 2: .Net

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how the notes field operates, it's more designed around displaying information in the multi-VM view where multi-line output wouldn't work.

If you're looking for something that can display multiple lines, in an prescriptive manner, look at using Tags or even Annotations/Custom Attributes.